# jupyterlab keyboardshortcuts: Which selector to use

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to set 3 keyboards shortcuts in jupyterlab. I go about this via settings / advanced settings editor / keyboard shortcuts, that's the only method I'm aware of.
I'm trying to set:

```
notebook:run-all-cells
notebook:run-all-above
notebook:run-all-below
```

I've experimented with the selectors that work for `restart-and-clear`: `"selector": "[data-jp-kernel-user]:focus"` and several others, not really understanding what they were to be honest, but I couldn't get it to work. Can someone tell me which selector I need to use here? How does one go about figuring this out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to run cells, presumably having one of the cells selected, I would use `[data-jp-code-runner]`, for example:

```
{
    "command": "notebook:run-all-cells",
    "keys": ["F9"],
    "selector": "[data-jp-code-runner]"
}
```

To discover a selector in the future you can search the list of existing shortcuts in the left panel. for example searching for `Shift Enter` or `run` keyword brings up:

```
        {
            "command": "runmenu:run",
            "keys": [
                "Shift Enter"
            ],
            "selector": "[data-jp-code-runner]"
        },
```

Alternatively you could:

- use just `body` if you want the shortcut to be always active (even though it may error if executed when focus is not on appropriate element)
- (advanced) use web developer inspector tool in your browser to determine the web query (CSS) selector for the element of interest

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had tried this selector already, the name did indeed suggest it was worth a random shot... But this doesn't work for me. Does it work for you? I tried on 2 installs; I'm able to set the shortcuts for some commands such as `kernelmenu:restart-and-clear` but the 3 I listed don't work for me so far.

Comment: Yes, I did test it prior to posting. Which version of JupyterLab are you using?

Comment: Hi @krassowski is there any documentation about what selectors are available and when to used them  ?

Comment: Yes, there is a section in the documentation named [commonly used CSS selectors](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/developer/css.html#commonly-used-css-selectors).